# Rails - Using Unless statement to exclude some items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, conditional-statements

I have the following model with the `unless` statement because I don't want to save Tweets which have both like and retweet equal to 0. However, when I run my script using the Twitter gem, I saved wrong tweets.

```
class Twit < ApplicationRecord

def self.get_tweets user
all_tweets = CLIENT.user_timeline(user, count: "20", exclude_replies: true, include_rts: false)
all_tweets.each do |tweet|
  unless (tweet.favorite_count == 0 && tweet.retweet_count == 0)
    Twit.find_or_create_by(link: "#{tweet.uri}") do |twit|
      twit.content = tweet.text
      twit.like = tweet.favorite_count
      twit.retweet = tweet.retweet_count
      twit.first_date = tweet.created_at
      twit.engagement == (tweet.favorite_count + tweet.retweet_count)
    end
  end
 end
end
```

Any hints? Thank you.

Comment: It may need to check for a string and not an integer.  Try changing the == 0 to:   == '0'

Comment: seems that `twitter` gem should return these numbers as Integers (can you verify it?) Can you inspect one of wrongly added tweets? that may help

Comment: @faron when I do `Twit.first.like.class` I get `Fixnum` so I guess it is not a string, right?

Comment: @Eric `Twit` is your class and and it may autoconvert passed value to int. We were asking about `tweet` (from `all_tweets.each do |tweet|`). Can you inspect first item to ensure that `favorite_count` and `retweet_count` are actually integers? Also would be really helpful to have this info for `tweet` that wrongly passes the check

Comment: @faron Sorry I misunderstood... Twitter Gem renders an integer for `#favorite_count ⇒ Integer` and `#retweet_count ⇒ Integer`

Comment: @faron when I do `all_tweets.first.favorite_count.class` I also get `Fixnum` as Class !

Comment: @Eric, nice, that's how it was supposed to work. Can you provide an example of `tweet` that is matched but shouldn't?

Comment: @faron for instance, this one has 0 like AND 0 retweet https://twitter.com/OpenCoconut/status/778950465090416640

Comment: @faron and I succeeded saving it to my database despite my condition...